# How to create a new directory using the results when running the "dir /b /s" on the command line

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm hoping this is possible in Windows batch:)

Based on a list of directories within a directory structure, is it possible to take the results of that list and append a directory name before/after/middle of the directory structure to create new directories?

For example, if I issue a `dir /b /s` command to a specific directory, it will list the directories within that directory as follows:

```
E:\ftproot\MiddlewareIO>dir /b /s

E:\ftproot\MiddlewareIO\Benefits
E:\ftproot\MiddlewareIO\Blackboard
E:\ftproot\MiddlewareIO\Data-Warehouse
E:\ftproot\MiddlewareIO\EmplWorkerDemo
E:\ftproot\MiddlewareIO\IDM
E:\ftproot\MiddlewareIO\PayrollData
E:\ftproot\MiddlewareIO\PayrollGLData
```

I would like to take the results from the directory list above and append the directory name "Archive" in the middle of the directory structure which will create this new directory structure.  The resulting structure is as follows:

```
E:\ftproot\MiddlewareIO\Archive\Benefits
E:\ftproot\MiddlewareIO\Archive\Blackboard
E:\ftproot\MiddlewareIO\Archive\Data-Warehouse
E:\ftproot\MiddlewareIO\Archive\EmplWorkerDemo
E:\ftproot\MiddlewareIO\Archive\IDM
E:\ftproot\MiddlewareIO\Archive\PayrollData
E:\ftproot\MiddlewareIO\Archive\PayrollGLData
```

This list can potentially grow and manually updating the batch file can be really tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

pushd E:\ftproot\MiddlewareIO

mkdir Archive

for /f "delims=\ tokens=1,2,3*" %%a in ('dir . /ad/s/b') do (
    mkdir "Archive\%%~d"
)

popd
```

You can also check if a directory exists before creating it:

```
@echo off

pushd E:\ftproot\MiddlewareIO

if not exist Archive\. mkdir Archive

for /f "delims=\ tokens=1,2,3*" %%a in ('dir . /ad/s/b') do (
    if not exist "Archive\%%~d\." mkdir "Archive\%%~d"
)

popd
```

New suggestion: Filter Archive out:

```
@echo off

pushd E:\ftproot\MiddlewareIO

if not exist Archive\. mkdir Archive

for /f "delims=\ tokens=1,2,3*" %%a in ('dir /ad /s /b ^| find /v "\Archive"') do (
    if not exist "Archive\%%~d\." mkdir "Archive\%%~d"
)

popd
```

Answer (score 0):

`for` command is your friend. Read `help for` and then try this in the command prompt

```
for /d %a in (*) do @echo %a
```

as you see, it follows all subfolders in the current directory.

thus,

```
for /d %a in (*) do @echo %cd%\Archive\%a
```

may fit your need